# Is there a pairing function from countable ordinals to $\mathbb N$?

Tags: set-theory, computability-theory

It is well-known that there is a computable pairing function $<\ >:\mathbb N^2\to \mathbb N$. Let $X$ be some reasonable class of countable ordinals ($\omega_1^{CK}$, $\epsilon_0$, $\omega^\omega$, or etc.). Is there any computable bijection from $X^2$ to $\mathbb N$? I would like to code pairs like $<\omega, 1>$ by some natural number and to recover the corresponding pair from a given natural number.

Comment: Turing machines and related usually cannot work with general ordinals, because they are infinitary concepts. Could you specify what you mean with "computable" in this case?

Comment: I mean: is there any computable way to code in a natural number the information of a pair like $<\omega,1>$?

Comment: *Reasonable* class of ordinals $\ X\ $ perhaps means that there is a reasonable way (algorithm) to assign $\ \mathbb N\ $ to them. Then you get $\ X^2\rightarrow \mathbb N^2\rightarrow \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coding the pairs from a set $X$ of ordinals is exactly as easy (or hard) as coding the individual elements of $X$.  That's because there are very easily computable pairing functions on the natural numbers.

If $X$ is small enough, like $\epsilon_0$, then this can be done computably, in the sense that there are algorithms for deciding whether a natural number is a code, deciding which of two codes represents the smaller ordinal, deciding whether a code represents a successor or limit ordinal, computing a code for the successor of an ordinal $\alpha$ when given a code for $\alpha$, computing the predecessor if $\alpha$ is a successor, and much more.  In the case of $\epsilon_0$, you can just take the Cantor normal form and Gödel number it to get a code.  There are similar but more complicated systems for lots of larger ordinals, in fact, for any proper initial segment of $\omega_1^{CK}$.  The key phrase to look up for (lots of) information about such things is "ordinal notations".

If you want to code all the ordinals below $\omega_1^{CK}$, rather than just a bounded initial segment of them, then you have to go beyond the computable, and even beyond the hyperarithmetical, in order to do the things I listed in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a way of representing recursive ordinals by integers, then surely you have a way of representing pairs of recursive ordinals by integers. A standard way of doing this is [Kleene's ordinal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).